# Wondering what the difference is between "much less" and "let alone"

Tags: word-meaning, let

> 1. Good luck getting the city to do anything, **much less** file an injunction. The mayor is very pro-business and it won’t look good if he tries to shut down any business that could bring revenue and jobs to this dying town.
> 2. Good luck getting the city to do anything, **let alone** file an injunction. The mayor is very pro-business and it won’t look good if he tries to shut down any business that could bring revenue and jobs to this dying town.

I have to say the number one is actual text taken from ESlPOD.COM
It was my intuation that the " much less" here means " let alone". 
Source: http://www.eslpod.com/website/show_podcast.php?issue_id=15193106

Answer (score 2):

In your context both phrases **much less + do something** and **let alone + do something** are interchangeable and are used in a negative context to add to one item another denoting something less likely, not even to take it into account, to an even greater degree.

Answer (score 0):

Both mean the same thing in the statements you showed us. They have a bad/negative meaning and in this case it means it's very unlikely to happen.